# Javascript Game - Objects Spawn on local copy, not once uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gamequery

I'm working on a basic, "avoid the falling objects" game in Javascript with GameQuery. Enemies Spawn often, and power ups periodically. The the power up spawn function is a copy of the enemy spawn function (shown below) with the variable names changed, and a different spawn rate/sprite. This works fine locally, however once uploaded to my site only the enemies spawn. What could be causing this? EnemyA = power ups.

[View the game here](http://www.piercecreative.ca/kiteflightbeta)

```
var enemyHeight = 48;
var enemyWidth = 48;
var enemySpawnRate = 700;
var enemyAHeight = 48;
var enemyAWidth = 48;
var enemyASpawnRate = 7000;

function Enemy(node, value){
  this.value = value;
  this.speed = 4 + passCount;
  this.node = node;
  this.update = function(){
    this.node.y(this.speed, true);
  };
};

function EnemyA(node, value){
  this.value = value;
  this.speed = 9;
  this.node = node;
  this.update = function(){
    this.node.y(this.speed, true);
  };
};



$(".enemy").each(function(){
    this.enemy.update();
    if(($(this).y()+ enemyHeight) > 640){
      passCount = passCount + 0.1;
      totalScore = totalScore + 50;
      $(this).remove();
    } else {
      var collided = $(this).collision("#playerBody,."+$.gQ.groupCssClass);
      if(collided.length > 0){
        $("#player")[0].player.value -= $(this)[0].enemy.value;
        $(this).remove();
        if($("#player")[0].player.value <= 0){
        $('.enemy').remove();
        $('.enemyA').remove();
            $("#playground").fadeOut(800);
            $("#gameover").delay(800).fadeIn(800);
            Enemy.speed = 0;

            $.playground().pauseGame();
        }
      }
    } 
  });
  $(".enemyA").each(function(){
    this.enemyA.update();
    if(($(this).y()+ enemyWidth) > 640){
      $(this).remove();
    } else {
      var collided = $(this).collision("#playerBody,."+$.gQ.groupCssClass);
      if(collided.length > 0){
        totalScore = totalScore + 250;
        playerSpeed = playerSpeed + 0.5;
        $(this).remove();
      }
    } 
  });

$.playground().registerCallback(function(){
  var enemyValue = 3;
  var name = "enemy_"+(new Date)  .getTime();
  $("#enemies").addSprite(name, {animation: enemySprite[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemySprite.length)], posy: 0, posx: Math.random()*PLAYGROUND_WIDTH*0.9,  width: enemyWidth, height: enemyHeight});
  var enemyElement = $("#"+name);
  enemyElement.addClass("enemy");
  enemyElement[0].enemy = new Enemy(enemyElement, enemyValue);
}, enemySpawnRate);

$.playground().registerCallback(function(){
  var enemyAValue = 100000;
  var name = "enemyA_"+(new Date)  .getTime();
  $("#enemiesA").addSprite(name, {animation: enemyASprite, posy: 0, posx: Math.random()*PLAYGROUND_WIDTH*0.9,  width: enemyAWidth, height: enemyAHeight});
  var enemyAElement = $("#"+name);
  enemyAElement.addClass("enemyA");
  enemyAElement[0].enemyA = new EnemyA(enemyAElement, enemyAValue);
}, enemyASpawnRate);
```

Comment: @Derek I considered that, however the issue is happening on every computer I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your game and found a sparkling looking thing. Grabbed it and I didn't die, is that a powerup? If so it looks like it's working fine from my end.

Comment: Works fine for me too (latest chrome and firefox on osx), power-ups spawn every 7 seconds like expected.

Comment: Turns out it was a rather simple error. The power-up gif's name had a capital in my javascript where there shouldn't have been. I'm unsure why it caused such inconsistency in showing the power-ups or not, but that was the cause.